# OWA Web Part Jumps/Shifts when getting focus on My Site

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts, outlook-web-app

In SharePoint (MOSS 2007), with an OWA web part on the page, either inbox or calendar parts, when a page loads it "jumps" down to have that part as the focus. No matter where it is on the page. Has anyone encountered this before or know how to solve this issue?

This happens on out of the box sharepoint sites, with the OWA components. No mofidications or 3rd party components or customizations are in play.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its by default. The webparts are designed to get the focus when loaded. 
Below might be solution/s using jQuery/JS:

1. Just create another webpart in the bottom (CE webpart just for adding JS) and add a JQUERY/JS code to scroll the page to top
2. Get to know the default JS function that's being called from the OWA webparts & override them in your custom JS

Nothing tested but normally this is how we prevent default behavior.